# C# MD5 hash function return weird result?

Tags: c#, utf-8, md5

I just tried to create a MD5 hash program in C#. My friend give me a sample code about this but when I try to run a test with "123456", instead of returning the correct hash result

> e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e

it returns the result

> ce0bfd15059b68d67688884d7a3d3e8c

I tried to read the main code but still cannot get anything!

```
string value = textBox1.Text;

byte[] valueBytes = new byte[value.Length * 2];

Encoder encoder = Encoding.Unicode.GetEncoder();
encoder.GetBytes(value.ToCharArray(), 0, value.Length, valueBytes, 0, true);

MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(valueBytes);

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2"));
}
textBox2.Text = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Comment: THere's nothing weird about C#'s MD5. Hashing alrgorithms return *bytes*, not strings. How you format the byte array into a string is up to you.

Comment: Unicode some characters are two bytes and some are one byte.  You are assuming all characters are two bytes.

Comment: @jdweng .NET strings are UTF16 and characters always take 2 bytes. Some codepoints may require two charaters to represent.

Comment: So how can I return it to the origin hash MD5 of "123456"?

Comment: @ABCD what original? What *were* the original bytes? Hashing works on *bytes* not strings. You converted the string into bytes using a UTF16 encoding. If you used a different one, eg ANSI, you'd get different bytes.

Comment: I try many way in Internet but it return MD5 hash is "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e".

Comment: If I want to show the result "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e", how can I return it to default?

Comment: No. No. No.  Characters in Net are two bytes with a private property indicating that a character is one or two bytes.  Encoding methods reads/sets the private property to determine if a character is one or two bytes.  So when bytes are converted to/from strings the results are unicode characters that can be either one or two bytes.

Comment: @ABCD who can people guess? How was it produced in the first place? The point of a cryptographic hash is that you *can't* find the original from the hash value.

Comment: @jdweng well in this case it's 2 bytes. `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("123456").Length` returns 12. Which characters would use *1* byte in the UTF16 encoding used by .NET ?

Comment: "correct hash result": As it has been said, hashing take bytes. The missing spec on what "correct" is, is using the "correct" character encoding, which converts text to bytes. The person that said what the correct result is is not communicating that. Ask.

Comment: In case anyone is assuming what `Encoding.Unicode` means: [Gets an encoding for the UTF-16 format using the little endian byte order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.unicode?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're expecting to have UTF8 string, so why do you use Unicode encoding? Use UTF8 and you'll get the result that you expect:

```
string value = "123456";

byte[] valueBytes = new byte[value.Length]; // <-- don't multiply by 2!

Encoder encoder = Encoding.UTF8.GetEncoder(); // <-- UTF8 here
encoder.GetBytes(value.ToCharArray(), 0, value.Length, valueBytes, 0, true);

MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(valueBytes);

StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < hashBytes.Length; i++)
{
    stringBuilder.Append(hashBytes[i].ToString("x2"));
}

Console.WriteLine(stringBuilder.ToString()); // "e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e"
```

Comment: Strings in .NET are UTF16. There's no such thing as a UTF8 string - yet.  As for the encoding used, it's US-ASCII, not UTF8. The first 127 bytes of UTF8 are identical to US-ASCII by design

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your friend used `Encoding.Default` instead of `Encoding.Unicode`

Strings in .NET are UTF16. Hashing works on *bytes* though, not strings. The string has to be converted to bytes. To do that, a specific encoding has to be used .

If the .NET native encoding is use, ie UTF16, the original byte buffer will be 12 bytes long and the hex representation of the hash will be `ce0bfd15059b68d67688884d7a3d3e8c` :

```
var valueBytes=Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("123456");
Debug.Assert(valueBytes.Length==12);
var md5=System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(valueBytes);
var hexText=String.Join("",hashBytes.Select(c=>c.ToString("x2")));
```

If the 7-bit *US-ASCII* encoding is used though, the array will be 6 bytes long and the hex representation will be `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e` :

```
var valueBytes=Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("123456");
Debug.Assert(valueBytes.Length==6);

var md5=System.Security.Cryptography.MD5.Create();
byte[] hashBytes = md5.ComputeHash(valueBytes);
var hexText=String.Join("",hashBytes.Select(c=>c.ToString("x2")));
```

The fist 127 bytes of most codepages match the 7-bit US-ASCII characters, so [most encodings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodinginfo.getencoding?view=netframework-4.7.2), including UTF8, would return `e10adc3949ba59abbe56e057f20f883e`. The following encodings would return the same hash string : `Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)` (Cyrillic), `Encoding.GetEncoding(20000)` (Chinese Traditiona) would result in the same hash.

The `Encoding.Default` value returns the encoding that corresponds to the computer's system locale. It's the encoding used by non-Unicode applications like C++ applications compiled with ANSI string types.

*Encoding.GetEncoding(20273)* though would return a different value - that's an IBM EBCDIC that used different bytes even for the english alphabet and digits. This will return : `73e00d17ee63efb9ae91d274baae2459`